# Make Parts of Trigger inactive with custom settings

Tags: apex, trigger

In production org the company have multiple triggers on same (User) object, which is against best practices. They should have only one trigger per object, but
how can System Administrator then in production make trigger inactive (when the part of the functionality is not needed anymore) If the trigger calls multiple controller classes with different business logic?

Comment: I believe I have done it in the past by pulling it into an IDE in a Sandbox.  I then deleted the Trigger on the server and pushed the changes from my IDE to production.  I can't remember if I had to delete the file in the IDE as well but keep a reference to it in the package or if I had to leave the trigger itself in my IDE.  This is running off memory as it's been years since I've had to do this.

Comment: There's a checkbox "Activated" on the triggers in sandboxes. So if you uncheck it, then deploy it to production, it must be deactivated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you describe would be to have a class that's configured which holds a boolean for each trigger to test whether or not it should run. You'd use either custom settings or custom metadata to set a value for a boolean that each Trigger would check in an "AppConfig" Class before running. The class would look something like this:

```
public with sharing class AppConfigSupport {

    public static Boolean Trigger_A_Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return GetAppConfig().TriggerAEnabled__c;
        }
    }

    public static Boolean Trigger_B_Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return GetAppConfig().TriggerBEnabled__c;
        }
    }   

}
```

In your trigger handler, you'd wrap all of the code inside an If clause that would test the boolean's value. If true, the handler runs. If false, it doesn't. It would look something like this:

```
If(AppConfigSupport.Trigger_A_Enabled){

    // Code for trigger handler class
    // .... 
}
```

You'd need to have a different boolean variable for each trigger you want to do this with.

Comment: This type of framework can also significantly reduce unit test time by disabling triggers you don't need to test. In one place I worked at, I reduced our deployment time by about 30 minutes using this.